# Saving data from API call to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have data coming from API call andd I want to save the assessmentId to my database. Here is my controller:

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$user_id = 95;
$this->loadModel('Persona');

$this->Persona->find('first',array('conditions'=> array('persona.user_id' => $user_id)));          
$data = array('user_id'=>$user_id,'key'=>'yCuZNjrOA2Pr0Y9WuAkZTTIQHwtWmkJK');
$Smart = $HttpSocket->post('https://sma..',$data);

$this->Persona->save($Smart['assessmentId']);

if($this->request->is('post'));
$this->request->data['Persona']['assessmentId'] = $this->request->data[["persona"]["assessmentId"];
$this->Persona->save($this->request->data);
endif;

$Smart = json_decode($Smartable,true);
$done = $HttpSocket->get('https://sma...'.$Smart['assessmentId']);
$done = json_decode($done,true);
```

Comment: So many issues here. Is that really a semi-colon on the end of the `if` line? That's a syntax error. There's another one in your assignment into the data array, where you have an extra `[`. But mostly, the problem seems to be that you're trying to save raw data. You can only save entities. The `$this->Persona->find` call will return an entity to you. Then you should use `$this->Persona->patchEntity` to update that.

Comment: what cake version? @GregSchmidt seems cake2.

Comment: That would indeed change things, though not the syntax errors...